# Getting the XML root node name

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, root

I have 2 xml files and one function to parse them. The function has to know how to parse them according to the xml document root node name.

How can I get the root name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the [name()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#name%28%29) or [localName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#localName%28%29) methods:

```
var xml:XML = <root><child /></root>
trace(xml.name());
trace(xml.localName());
```

Answer (score 3):

use the [name](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#name%28%29) function of the XML object:

```
var xml1:XML=<foo></foo>
var xml2:XML=<bar></bar>
function parse(xml:XML):void{
    trace(xml.name())
}
parse(xml1) // trace foo
parse(xml2) // trace bar
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have this XML:

```
var xml:XML = <TheRootNode><someData /></TheRootNode>;
```

Then to get the root node, you just call `name()`:

```
Alert.show(xml.name()); // Displays "TheRootNode"
```

Cheers!